# How to secure requests between Android and PHP

Tags: php, android

So I've been literally 2 months searching for this but nothing... Basically I've got an Android app witch makes HTTP(S) requests to a PHP server. Let's say I've got a URL to get some information: https://example.com/username/check/whaterver/, to access this URL you need to send over a token that you get once you're logged in. I have everythig all set, the only problem is that I know that people can see the requests made from their phones, let's say: URL: https://example.com Form-data: token=5456432145. What I need is a way to send the token to the server without the user being able to see the token.

I am not asking how to make a HTTP request between Android and PHP, I'm asking how to ONLY accept HTTP requests from Android and PHP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make an HTTP request with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android)

Comment: You don't need secure request (only HTTPS is enought) from client (Android) and PHP because user have many way to get it. You must protect you data from server by code

Comment: can't you make https request to the php server in the background of the app as an api call ?

Comment: I think the usual practice for security token is to:  1. send them throught POST parameter or header; and 2. simply have them expire in a relatively short period of time; and 3. only send them throught HTTPS.

Comment: If you really want to obscure the token text from even the client system, you may take a look at asymmetric encryption of any sort. You may [encrypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-private-decrypt.php) the request, with token, on Android then [decrypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-private-decrypt.php) on server. But if the user has access to the memory of the device, he / she may still get the token and encryption key.

Comment: Thanks @KoalaYeung I'll go with the expiration time!

Answer (score -1):

You can use/create a cryptography to send to PHP server and from server to browser of device. A cryptography mode will encode your token code.
Like: token=5456432145 to token=D37AG3H7183BAD2E6DGAS